# How to detect file_get_contents is returning gzipped content

Tags: php, http-headers, gzip

Im using the following to get the url of a video on my site.

```
$vid = 231231; 
$url = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/") 
echo $url ;
```

**Please note:** the `$vid` variable is dynamic and sometimes, it returns `gziped` content.

I already know that I can use the `gzdecode` function to unzip that content like this:

```
$vid = 231231; 
$url = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/") 
$decodeit = gzdecode($url);
echo $decodeit;
```

Now, the problem is I need to find a way to decode the `$url` variable, only if needed. By "**needed**", I mean: if (`$url`) it's returning `gziped` content because I need to use the same code to the same source.

Is it possible to do some checking, here? How?

Comment: Check the first two bytes? Have you looked at gzip file format?

Answer (score 3):

After the call to `file_get_contents`, [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) will return the response headers, including the status code.

The [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) header specifies which encoding was used, for example the header `Content-Encoding: gzip` would specify that the content is encoded with `gzip`.

So I'd write a function to map the headers into an array `header name => value`, and then check for the `Content-Encoding` entry to determine whether the response is compressed with gzip or not.

**Create map from header name to value**

```
function transformIntoHeaderMap(array $headers)
{
```

Get rid of the status header (e.g. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`), as it does not fit in the `header name: value` format.

```
    $headersWithValues = array_filter($headers, function ($header) { return strpos($header, ':') !== false; });
```

Now split the headers at `:` and write key and value into the map. Trim the value, to get rid of whitespaces at the beginning/end.

```
    $headerMap = [];
    foreach ($headersWithValues as $header) {
            list($key, $value) = explode(':', $header);
            $headerMap[$key] = trim($value);
    }

    return $headerMap;
}
```

**Determine whether the content is gzipped**

Check whether the header is set, and then check whether it has the value you're looking for (`gzip`).

```
function isGzipHeaderSet(array $headerMap)
{
    return isset($headerMap['Content-Encoding']) && 
        $headerMap['Content-Encoding'] == 'gzip';
}
```

**Unzip content if it was gzipped**

```
$vid = 231231; 
$contents = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/");
if (isGzipHeaderSet(transformIntoHeaderMap($http_response_header))) {
    $contents = gzdecode($contents);
}

echo $contents;
```

**Alternative**

A simpler approach might be to use `array_search` and look directly for the string `Content-Encoding: gzip` in `$http_response_header`. But I think this approach is more robust regarding whitespaces in the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Content-Type or Content-Encoding in [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php).

Comment: how can I do that (check if `$url` is returning gziped content) on this context?

Comment: @Alex That is explained in the article Kjartan linked in his answer. `$http_response_header` Is defined by the `file_get_contents` function and you can loop trough the array it contains to find what content type is returned.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative in some cases by using the HTTP REQUEST HEADERS.

```
 $httpHeaders = array(
        "header" =>
            array("Accept-Encoding: identity")
        );

  $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $httpHeaders));


  $response = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/", false, $context );
```

The **identity** value in the **Encoding** header indicates that content should be returned without modification, you can [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding). Which means that shouldn't be compressed in any way.

Take into account the size of the response before doing this, as you might be increasing the amount of bandwidth used by the the provider of the endpoint.